# Support VHDL syntax highlighting

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

We now have syntax highlighting for a host of languages through Google Prettify.  Regrettably, the default set:

```
lang-bsh
lang-c
lang-cpp
lang-cs
lang-csh
lang-css
lang-hs
lang-html
lang-java
lang-js
lang-lisp
lang-lua
lang-ml
lang-perl
lang-php
lang-proto
lang-py
lang-rb
lang-scala
lang-sh
lang-sql
lang-vb
lang-xml
```

doesn't include VHDL, which (based on a comparison of the [vhdl](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vhdl), [verilog](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verilog), and [asm](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asm) tags) is the second-most used language on our site (The first is [c](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c), of course...).

VHDL [already has a plugin](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/source/browse/trunk/src/lang-vhdl.js) for Google Prettify.  If this is enabled, we'll be better able to serve this portion of our community.

Comment: This was never really addressed, but is there an issue using the VHDL plugin for Google Prettify?

Comment: @W5VO - None that I'm aware of.

Comment: @W5VO - After some more research, I've discovered that the TeX site got a plugin for TeX: [Syntax highlighting](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/10) so this seems to be possible.

Answer (score 10):

We have added support for vhdl using the prettify plugin.  This should work after the next deploy.